# magento 1 append block into another block

Tags: checkout, magento-1, billing-address

I have google map section as one block .
and i want to add my block into checkout billing address block.
i did like this code

```
<reference name="content">

  <reference name="checkout.onepage">
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
      <block  type="core/template"  name="delivery_index"  template="delivery/index.phtml" />
    </reference>
 </reference>
</reference>
```

but that did not work ! 
is there any way for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to rewrite the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media .

In my class I over-rid the function _toHtml function like this:

```
public function _toHtml()
{
    $html = parent::_toHtml();
    $html.=$this->getChildHtml('media_video');
    return $html;
}
```

where "media_video" is my block. My layout xml file:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="product.info">
            <reference name="product.info.media">
            <block type="myblock/myblock" name="somename" as="media_video" template="beta/abc.phtml"
                   before="-"/>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

This will add videos to product page along with images

But you can Take some idea from above code to place **block on another block**

Comment: it is my code 
`  <checkout_onepage_index>


    <reference name="content">

      <reference name="checkout.onepage">
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
          <block  type="core/template"  name="delivery_index"  template="delivery/index.phtml" />

        </reference>
     </reference>
    </reference>
  </checkout_onepage_index>
`
but it did not work ...do you have any idea?

Comment: @chiya i have updated the code in answer

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written seems correct. Please check the following things:

- Enable template path hints to check whether the files are being called from checkout module or persistent module.
- Based on above step, make necessary changes in the correct layout XML file.
- Check whether you have respective closing tag **`</reference>`** for **`<reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">`** in your XML file.
- In the respective billing.phtml file, call the following line:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('delivery_index');?>
```

That's all. Refresh cache and check the page again.

Comment: i close 'reference' correctly... 
for another is important checkout template(phtml) overrided by another module ?

Comment: You can call getChildHtml from overrided phtml file.

Comment: you are right but i went to create module that worked on all website with any template .... is it imposible ?